# How to split a nested list into multiple nested lists?

Tags: python, list, split, nested, group

I have a nested list shaped like
`mylist = [[a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, h], [i, j, k, l]]`
And i need to split the nested lists so that every two items are grouped together like this:
`Nested_list = [[[a, b], [c, d], [[e, f], [g, h]], [[i, j], [k, l]]`

I tried splitting them by them by usinga for loop that appended them but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

```
mylist = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l']]

nested_list = [ [i[:2], i[2:]] for i in mylist ] 

print(nested_list)
```

Output:

```
[[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']], [['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']], [['i', 'j'], ['k', 'l']]]
```

Comment: best method for sure

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l']]
Nested_list = []
for x in mylist:
    Nested_list.append(x[:2])
    Nested_list.append(x[2:])
print(Nested_list)
```

Output: [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h'], ['i', 'j'], ['k', 'l']]

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

Nested_list = np.array(mylist).reshape(-1,2,2)
```

output:

```
array([[['a', 'b'],
        ['c', 'd']],

       [['e', 'f'],
        ['g', 'h']],

       [['i', 'j'],
        ['k', 'l']]], dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Im working with a dataset made up off 32870 entries, and these need to be sorted in 173 lists of 190 different lists made up off 2 items. By using your method i close to finishing it but i ended up with an output where there are three lists but hey arent grouped correctly. It now looks like:
[[['a', 'b'],
        ['c', 'd'],

       ['e', 'f'],
        ['g', 'h'],

       ['i', 'j'],
        ['k', 'l']]]
The method i used is:
    final_list = np.array(clean_list).reshape(-1,16435,2)
    final_list2 = final_list.tolist()
How can i fix this? Thanks in a

Comment: @Nasrr sorry, but I can't properly understand what's your new task. Can you open a new question with a better description of your input and your desired output? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import * 

my_list = chain.from_iterable(my_list)
def grouper(inputs, n):
    iters = [iter(inputs)] * n
    return zip_longest(*iters)

print(list(grouper(my_list, 2)))
```

Comment: Please add explanations to your code. Code only is not an answer.